# how can I extract values from this dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, dataset, key-value

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{"message":"{\"_\":\"user\",\"pFlags\":{\"contact\":true},\"flags\":2175,\"id\":379951860,\"access_hash\":\"6967195540985199805\",\"first_name\":\"پژوا\",\"last_name\":\"روزبهی\",\"username\":\"mramtd2\",\"phone\":\"989157145632\",\"photo\":{\"_\":\"userProfilePhoto\",\"photo_id\":\"1631880813210609625\",\"photo_small\":{\"_\":\"fileLocation\",\"dc_id\":4,\"volume_id\":\"448413446\",\"local_id\":476387,\"secret\":\"655623158723369503\"},\"photo_big\":{\"_\":\"fileLocation\",\"dc_id\":4,\"volume_id\":\"448413446\",\"local_id\":476389,\"secret\":\"13993366131879811943\"}},\"status\":{\"_\":\"userStatusOffline\",\"was_online\":1558046876}}","phone":"989157145632","@version":"1","typ":"telegram_contacts","access_hash":"6967195540985199805","id":379951860,"@timestamp":"2020-01-26T13:50:12.793Z","path":"/home/user/mirror_01/users_5d65f610ec18aa615a5f580c.log","username":"mramtd2","type":"redis","flags":2175,"host":"ubuntu","imported_from":"telegram_contacts"}
```

how can I extract `first_name`, `last_name`, `id` and `phone` values from this dictionary?

Comment: Is this dictionnary is comming from a JSON file / string ?

Comment: @FélixHerbinet 
No. from text file

Comment: Can you copy/paste the content of the file please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, assuming your file has new line delimited dictionaries, using below code solved the issue:

```
import json
fo = open(r"C:\Users\Downloads\test.txt", "r")
for each_line in fo.readlines():
    print(json.loads(json.loads(each_line)['message'])['first_name'])
    print(json.loads(json.loads(each_line)['message'])['last_name'])
    print(json.loads(json.loads(each_line)['message'])['id'])
    print(json.loads(json.loads(each_line)['message'])['phone'])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import json

# I have assumed your dictionary like that
data = {"message":"{\"_\":\"user\",\"pFlags\":{\"contact\":true},\"flags\":2175,\"id\":379951860,\"access_hash\":\"6967195540985199805\",\"first_name\":\"پژوا\",\"last_name\":\"روزبهی\",\"username\":\"mramtd2\",\"phone\":\"989157145632\",\"photo\":{\"_\":\"userProfilePhoto\",\"photo_id\":\"1631880813210609625\",\"photo_small\":{\"_\":\"fileLocation\",\"dc_id\":4,\"volume_id\":\"448413446\",\"local_id\":476387,\"secret\":\"655623158723369503\"},\"photo_big\":{\"_\":\"fileLocation\",\"dc_id\":4,\"volume_id\":\"448413446\",\"local_id\":476389,\"secret\":\"13993366131879811943\"}},\"status\":{\"_\":\"userStatusOffline\",\"was_online\":1558046876}}","phone":"989157145632","@version":"1","typ":"telegram_contacts","access_hash":"6967195540985199805","id":379951860,"@timestamp":"2020-01-26T13:50:12.793Z","path":"/home/user/mirror_01/users_5d65f610ec18aa615a5f580c.log","username":"mramtd2","type":"redis","flags":2175,"host":"ubuntu","imported_from":"telegram_contacts"}

# The data in "message" need to be loaded on JSON format to access it.
data["message"] = json.loads(data["message"])

# Now, you can print or whatever you want with all the data
print(data["message"]["id"])
print(data["message"]["first_name"])
print(data["message"]["last_name"])
print(data["message"]["phone"])  # There is phone info both in data["message"]["phone"] and data["phone"]. They are identical. You can use whichever you want.

# Optional
# If you want, you can assign data["message"] to a variable.
finalData = data["message"]

# Then you can access the info that you need from finalData
print(finalData["first_name"])
```

Comment: your answer is true. But I have a Large Text file and it has multiple dictionary like that. How can I do that?

Comment: Does each line contain a dictionary, or is there a main dictionary or list containing all dictionaries?

Answer (score 1):

You should turn the string into a dictionary using e.g. `json.loads`. Then extract like from a normal nested dictionary.

Example:

```
import json
message = mydict["message"]
message_dict = json.loads(message)
message_dict['id']
```

where `mydict` is your given input dictionary.

In case your snippet shows the content of a file, you could do the following:

```
with open(filepath) as file:
    mydict = json.load(file)
message_dict = mydict["message"]
message_dict['id']
```

Comment: this is a text file

Comment: You should clarify in the question that your snippet is not code, but the content of a file.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could show us some code lines to better understand where you got stuck. Is it opening the file? Is it reading the values into a variable? Is it parsing the json fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to extract those values:

```py
import json

str1 = r'{"message":"{\"_\":\"user\",\"pFlags\":{\"contact\":true},\"flags\":2175,\"id\":379951860,\"access_hash\":\"6967195540985199805\",\"first_name\":\"پژوا\",\"last_name\":\"روزبهی\",\"username\":\"mramtd2\",\"phone\":\"989157145632\",\"photo\":{\"_\":\"userProfilePhoto\",\"photo_id\":\"1631880813210609625\",\"photo_small\":{\"_\":\"fileLocation\",\"dc_id\":4,\"volume_id\":\"448413446\",\"local_id\":476387,\"secret\":\"655623158723369503\"},\"photo_big\":{\"_\":\"fileLocation\",\"dc_id\":4,\"volume_id\":\"448413446\",\"local_id\":476389,\"secret\":\"13993366131879811943\"}},\"status\":{\"_\":\"userStatusOffline\",\"was_online\":1558046876}}","phone":"989157145632","@version":"1","typ":"telegram_contacts","access_hash":"6967195540985199805","id":379951860,"@timestamp":"2020-01-26T13:50:12.793Z","path":"/home/user/mirror_01/users_5d65f610ec18aa615a5f580c.log","username":"mramtd2","type":"redis","flags":2175,"host":"ubuntu","imported_from":"telegram_contacts"}'

print(json.loads(json.loads(str1)['message'])['first_name'])
print(json.loads(json.loads(str1)['message'])['last_name'])
print(json.loads(json.loads(str1)['message'])['id'])
print(json.loads(json.loads(str1)['message'])['phone'])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to do it:

```
import json

D = {"message":"{\"_\":\"user\",\"pFlags\":{\"contact\":true},\"flags\":2175,\"id\":379951860,\"access_hash\":\"6967195540985199805\",\"first_name\":\"پژوا\",\"last_name\":\"روزبهی\",\"username\":\"mramtd2\",\"phone\":\"989157145632\",\"photo\":{\"_\":\"userProfilePhoto\",\"photo_id\":\"1631880813210609625\",\"photo_small\":{\"_\":\"fileLocation\",\"dc_id\":4,\"volume_id\":\"448413446\",\"local_id\":476387,\"secret\":\"655623158723369503\"},\"photo_big\":{\"_\":\"fileLocation\",\"dc_id\":4,\"volume_id\":\"448413446\",\"local_id\":476389,\"secret\":\"13993366131879811943\"}},\"status\":{\"_\":\"userStatusOffline\",\"was_online\":1558046876}}","phone":"989157145632","@version":"1","typ":"telegram_contacts","access_hash":"6967195540985199805","id":379951860,"@timestamp":"2020-01-26T13:50:12.793Z","path":"/home/user/mirror_01/users_5d65f610ec18aa615a5f580c.log","username":"mramtd2","type":"redis","flags":2175,"host":"ubuntu","imported_from":"telegram_contacts"}

data = json.loads(D['message'])

for key in ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'id']:
    print(f'{key} -> {data.get(key, "?")}')
```